# How to get access to saved entity in a listener?

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine

I am working on a project based on Symfony 2. I have registered a listener like so:

```
services:
    app.video_release_listener:
        class: CmsBundle\EventListener\Video\VideoReleaseListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

... and my listener class looks like this:

```
namespace CmsBundle\EventListener\Video;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Video;

class VideoReleaseListener
{
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args){
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        die(get_class($entity));
    }
}
```

... which I had hoped would spit out the class name of my video entity when I saved a video. Instead, it spits out `Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry` -- not what I want.

**How do I get access to my video entity from within the listener?**

====

Edit: I also tried putting a conditional check of the class around my `die()` statement in order to see whether there was perhaps another iteration with a different object. No second iteration occurs.

Comment: That looks right to me. Since you're calling `die`, are you sure this isn't just the first iteration of the function (i.e. a different entity being persisted)? A common pattern for `postPersist` is to check `if ($entity instanceof Foo)` at the top, since your listener will be called for every entity being persisted.

Comment: Good guess about this being the first iteration. I tried a more complex version of the logic to test for a second iteration, and none occurs. This appears to be the sole time that the listener gets called.

Comment: Are you perhaps updating an already existing entity? Did you try the `if ($entity instanceof YourEntity)` pattern at the top of your method?

Comment: Yep -- tried that. It didn't match at all. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly fix the issue as described, but I got around it by adding an `@ORM\EntityListeners` tag on my `video` class like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"CmsBundle\EventListener\Video\VideoReleaseListener"})
*/
```

... and then switching my VideoReleaseListener method name to `postUpdate()`. (It refused to work as `postPersist()` for some reason.)

Anyhow, it's very flaky behavior, but maybe this helps someone.